# Read parent location from within a frame (different domains)

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, cross-domain

**How could an iframe read its parent location URL**, the domains of the parent window and the iframe being different?

I know that the "common" answer to this question is that because of the domains conflict, browsers don't allow cross-domain accesses.
So the following **won't work**:

```
parent.location.href
```

But maybe someone could think *out of the box* here and propose something similar to the [Cross-document messaging hack](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000304.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!!

My solution is the following:

**1. Use the *onload* attribute with the frame**

```
<iframe src="http://website.com/" onload="src+='#'+document.location"></iframe>
```

**2. Monitor hash changes in the frame**

```
var referrer = '?';
window.onhashchange = function() {
  var ref = document.location.hash;
  if(ref && ref.length > 1) {
    var t = ref.split('#');
    ref = t[1];
  }
  referrer = ref;
};
```

And "voilà" :-)

By the way, you'll find some more details about the [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) event.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could check [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer)? Of course, that will only work if the user has not yet clicked a link inside the iframe.

Comment: Nope, it returns nothing from within the frame.

Comment: @PleaseStand this really helped a lot. Thanks!